# Prove that a linear map is 0 if its $o(\|h\|)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $L: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map such that $L\vec{h} = o(\|\vec{h}\|)$. Show that $L = 0$. Any help on this?

The assumption means that 
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{L(\vec{h})}{\|\vec{h}\|} = 0. 
$$

How does this imply that $L = 0$?

The only idea so far that I had is that since $L$ is linear we have for the derivative
$$
L(\vec{a} + \vec{h}) - L(\vec{a}) = L\vec{h} = o(\|\vec{h}\|)
$$
But how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: suppose $L(x)\neq 0$ and consider $L(ax),a\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have made the following attempt now: 

Suppose not, then $L(\vec{x}) \neq 0$ for some $\vec{x} \neq 0$. Now consider $a\vec{x}$ for $a \to 0^+$. Then $a\vec{x} \to 0$. Then we have 
$$
\lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{L(a\vec{x})}{\|a\vec{x}\|} = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{aL(\vec{x})}{|a|\|\vec{x}\|} = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{L(\vec{x})}{\|\vec{x}\|} \neq 0. 
$$
But $L(a\vec{x}) = o(\|a\vec{x}\|)$, so we have $\lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{L(a\vec{x})}{\|a\vec{x}\|} = \lim_{a\vec{x} \to \vec{0}} \frac{L(a\vec{x})}{\|a\vec{x}\|} = 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure about the details, in particular, it is possible to take $a \to 0^+$, otherwise the term $\frac{a}{|a|}$ might not cancel.

Comment: That's correct. Just taking $a\to 0^+$ would indeed be sensible - the term $a/|a|$ doesn't make much difference, but it's easier if it's gone.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}{Lh\over|h|}=0\ .$$
Given an arbitrary unit vector $e$, put $h:=t\,e$ with $t>0$. Then
$$Le={1\over t}L(t\, e)={Lh\over|h|}\to0\qquad(t\to0+)\ .$$
It follows that the constant $Le$ is in fact $=0$.